# Send Template Email Using Struts2 View

Tags: struts2, html-email, apache-tiles

I am using Struts2, and I want to send the html output of one of my actions as an email.
In other words, instead of displaying the output html in the browser, I want to send it as an email.

I am using Apache Tiles to create my pages.

EDIT:
In general, can we get the the html result of struts view as a stream and pass it to another action?

Comment: Struts works with streams but it's unclear how would you like to pass a stream to the action?

Comment: Technically, sure, but I'm almost positive this isn't the approach I'd take. I'd rather the email was constructed using something like FreeMarker/etc and handled that way.

Comment: @DaveNewton, imagine the case that you already have a jsp version of that template, and you want to give the user the option to email it. Then creating a new template needs double maintenance

Comment: I understand the issue. The problem is that is difficult and fragile to use JSP in this way unless you have a JSP engine outside of an app container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I need to mention that using JSPs as email templates are not a good idea. But, if you need to do this, or you need to log the exact HTML that user sees (or any other reason), you can do this:

1. Create an interceptor for your action
2. Get the response from ServletActionContext
3. Wrap the response
4. Invoke the action
5. get (or even change) the response.
6. return the result.

This is part of my code:

```
import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

//STEP 1
public class EmailInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
        // STEP 2
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        // STEP 3
        CharResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

        ServletActionContext.setResponse(responseWrapper);
        // STEP 4
        String result = actionInvocation.invoke();
        // STEP 5
        String servletResponse = new String(responseWrapper.toString());
        out.write(servletResponse + "whatever");
        // STEP 6
        return result;

    }

    public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
        private CharArrayWriter output;

        public String toString() {
            return output.toString();
        }

        public CharResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(response);
            output = new CharArrayWriter();
        }

        public PrintWriter getWriter() {
            return new PrintWriter(output);
        }
    }

}
```